# Drupal 8 and Patternlab

Tags: drupal, patternlab.io

I am doing a composer install of patternlab with Drupal 8.

I installed the minimal starterkit theme to source/. when i run php core/console --generate i get the message "your styleguide won't render because I cannot find your styleguide files. are you sure they are at .\C:\xampp5.6.28\htdocs\sitename\patternlab\vendor/pattern-lab/styleguidekit-twig-default".

The path is correct but i don't know what styleguide files are? Sounds a bit silly I know. Please help me here, i just need to know what files need to be in that folder. I really have spent many hours Googling, but I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: If you haven't already, run the command inside the pattern-lab directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I think the issue is only Windows machine.

styleguideKitPath in config/config.yml must be relative from vendor/.

styleguideKit: pattern-lab/styleguidekit-twig-default
styleguideKitPath: 'vendor/pattern-lab/styleguidekit-twig-default'

When generating the path added is absolute. Although the path is correct, it needs a relative path like above.